# Mysql max connections and event scheduler

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

Is there a limit to how many "instance" of a scheduled event MySQL can run? I have set this up:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (c1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL) ENGINE=INNODB;

SELECT * FROM t;

DELIMITER $$

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS e_second;
CREATE EVENT e_second ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
    SELECT SLEEP(1000);
    INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SELECT * FROM t;

SHOW PROCESSLIST;

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%';
```

This creates a dumb event started every second, that runs for 1000 seconds. In my query log, I indeed have:

```
2020-02-18T15:47:00.289050Z      1016 Query     INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
2020-02-18T15:47:00.430801Z      1216 Query     INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
2020-02-18T15:47:00.430950Z      1216 Query     SELECT SLEEP(200)
2020-02-18T15:47:01.290518Z      1017 Query     INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
2020-02-18T15:47:01.430943Z      1217 Query     INSERT INTO t (c1) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
...
```

So the event is run every second, and hangs (on purpose). Now, the processlist shows (after a while):

```
"559"   "root-heidisql" "127.0.0.1" "test_sql"  "Connect"   "702"   "User sleep"    "SELECT SLEEP(1000)"
"560"   "root-heidisql" "127.0.0.1" "test_sql"  "Connect"   "701"   "User sleep"    "SELECT SLEEP(1000)"
"561"   "root-heidisql" "127.0.0.1" "test_sql"  "Connect"   "700"   "User sleep"    "SELECT SLEEP(1000)"
"562"   "root-heidisql" "127.0.0.1" "test_sql"  "Connect"   "699"   "User sleep"    "SELECT SLEEP(1000)"
"563"   "root-heidisql" "127.0.0.1" "test_sql"  "Connect"   "698"   "User sleep"    "SELECT SLEEP(1000)"
...
```

So I have about 528 rows in this processlist now. But, my connections limit is `151` as shown by showing variables:

```
"max_connections"   "151"
```

So clearly, the running events are not part of the connections limit. Then, what is the limit? Is there one?

It feels to me that at some point, some mysql queue/list/whatever will be full of the pending events... Is this case documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes. Connection limit means outer connections, event scheduler is not counted. But there is a lot of another limited resources - limited by some settings or by some physical conditions. And it is too problematic to find what resource limits the server.

Comment: @Akina Ok, but besides implicit limitations (memory, pools etc), there is no direct limitation of the number of currently running events? I cannot set some variable like "max_event_runnings = 100" and be sure no more than 100 events would be run at the same time?

Comment: *there is no direct limitation of the number of currently running events?* Yes, such limitation not exists. MySQL treates an event as a trigger which fires on a timer event - and there is no limitation on the number of triggers in the system. In general the event procedure must check does its previous instance have already finished its work...

Comment: Alrght, thanks! you may make an answer from it if you want me to accept it.

Comment: I'll tell you what I tell `cron` users who run a process that may take longer than the cycle time:  "Don't".  Events and Crons should be much faster than the frequency given.  Else don't use Event or Cron, but simply have a process that loops forever.

Comment: @RickJames That would require to also code a "revival-process" in case your infinite loop crashes (which might happen). Tho, where did I talk about the cron task duration? It was only used for showcasing what happen when more events are running than the connection limit.

Comment: @Xenos - Do you need more than one instance of the Event running at the same time?  If so, why launch with `EVENT` instead of the app spawning something?

Comment: @RickJames I don't currently have any real case for that, it's only a wondering I got ;) And I wondered that by thinking "if I have a web application where an event is supposed to happen at a specified time, then I could make the application spawn the event using DB event... But what if the application spawns 10k events? will I reach a limit like for connections?" In the end, I don't need  such spawn at all (because the best is only to store the "when should X happen" date in DB column, and compute all past things on page display) but the wondering is still interesting enough to be posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the running events are not part of the connections limit. Then, what is the limit? Is there one?

Connection limit means outer connections, event scheduler is not counted. But there is a lot of another limited resources - limited by some settings or by some physical conditions. And it is too problematic to find what resource limits the server.

> there is no direct limitation of the number of currently running events?

Yes, such limitation not exists. MySQL treates an event as a trigger which fires on a timer event - and there is no limitation on the number of triggers in the system.

In general the event procedure must check does its previous instance have already finished its work... by using some flag field/value in a service table, for example, or by some another mark.